# Use sed to replace patterns that are not at the start of end of lines

Tags: regex, sed

Let's say I have input:

```
/a/b/c/d/e/
/a/b/c/d/e
a/b/c/d/e/
a/b/c/d/e
```

I'd like to replace all `/` that are not at the edges with `+` so the output is:

```
/a+b+c+d+e/
/a+b+c+d+e
a+b+c+d+e/
a+b+c+d+e
```

I've tried this command:

```
sed -e "s#\(.\)/\(.\)#\1+\2#g"
```

which is close but not quite:

```
/a+b/c+d/e/
/a+b/c+d/e
a+b/c+d/e/
a+b/c+d/e
```

presumably because the `\(.\)` overlap between successive `/` characters.

I don't believe sed has a null match operator for beginning or end of line. So, how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate all slashes to `+` and then replace + (at the beginning or at the end) with a slash:

```
sed 'y/\//+/;s/^+\|+$/\//g;'
```

or if the OR operator isn't available:

```
sed 'y/\//+/;s/^+/\//;s/+$/\//;'
```

better if you change the delimiter to avoid to escape all literal slashes:

```
sed 'y~/~+~;s~^+\|+$~/~g;'
```

or if the OR operator isn't available:

```
sed 'y~/~+~;s~^+~/~;s~+$~/~;'
```

*(where `^` is an anchor for the start of the line and `$` for the end)*

---

Other way: you can protect the slashes you want to preserve using a placeholder:

```
sed 's~^/~{`%{~;s~/$~{`%{~;y~/~+~;s~{`%{~/~g;'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `perl` you can use lookarounds for this:

```
perl -pe 's~(?<!^)/(?!$)~+~g' file
```

**Output:**

```
/a+b+c+d+e/
/a+b+c+d+e
a+b+c+d+e/
a+b+c+d+e
```

Otherwise you can use this `sed` with 2 substitutes:

```
sed -r 's~(.)/(.)~\1+\2~g; s~(.)/(.)~\1+\2~g' file
```

Or this sed with labeling and looping:

```
sed -r ':a;s|(.)/(.)|\1+\2|g;ta' file
```

Comment: or with a small change: `sed -r ':a;s|(.)/(.)|\1+\2|g;ta' file`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Cyrus, adding it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sed command that gives your output:

```
sed -r 's=(.)/\b=\1+=g;' file
```

- usually `/` is uses as separator for the s command, but here we use `=`
- the `/` is matched where there is something (`.`) before it and and we are at a word boundary
- initially I tried `(.)/(.)` but that did not work:

  - The second dot was consumed and the next match would only start after it,
  - i.e. in `x/y/<` the second match would only see `/z` and not `y/z`
  - with `\b` the first match does not consume the `y` and the second match sees `y/`

Answer (score 0):

This is the common and extremely useful sed idiom for doing jobs like this:

```
$ sed 's:a:aA:g; s:^/\|/$:aB:g; s:/:+:g; s:aB:/:g; s:aA:a:g' file
/a+b+c+d+e/
/a+b+c+d+e
a+b+c+d+e/
a+b+c+d+e
```

The 1st sub changes all `a`s to `aA`. At that point there is no letter `a` in the input that is not followed by the letter `A` (we need to do this first to ensure that after our 2nd sub the only `aB`s in the input are as a result of that 2nd sub)

The 2nd sub changes all `/`s at the start or end of a line to `aB`. At that point the only `aB`s in the input are where there were originally `/`s at the start or end of the line.

The 3rd sub changes all remaining `/`s (i.e. those that were not at the start or end of the line) to `+`s.

The 4th sub restores the `aB`s back to the original front/end `/`s.

The 5th sub restores the `aA`s back to the original `a`s.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;s/\([^\/]\)\/\([^\/]\)/\1+\2/g;ta' file
```

Or visually easier:

```
sed -r ':a;s#([^/])/([^/])#\1+\2#g;ta' file
```

It is really the same regexp twice:

```
sed 's/\([^\/]\)\/\([^\/]\)/\1+\2/g;s/\([^\/]\)\/\([^\/]\)/\1+\2/g' file
```